# elasticsearch/logstash and logstash-contrib: Couldn't find any plugin named 'x'

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use the 'cloudtrail' codec with logstash **1.4.2**, which is in logstash-contrib. I've installed it on an ubuntu distro:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin --install elasticsearch/logstash-contrib
```

I've verified the file is there:

```
ls /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/logstash-contrib/_site/lib/logstash/codecs/cloudtrail.rb
```

And I've included it in a basic configuration:

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "bucketname"
    delete => false
    codec => "cloudtrail"

....
```

When I try to run it, I get a plugin error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-02-06T20:10:25.179000+0000", :message=>"
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |                               
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |    
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |                     
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is: 
  Couldn't find any codec plugin named 'cloudtrail'. Are you sure
 this is correct? Trying to load the cloudtrail codec plugin resulted
 in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/codecs/cloudtrail"}
```

Now, I see that most of the codecs are at `/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/codecs`. Do I need to manually copy it (that seems bad)? Is there a gem install I'm missing?

For the fun of it, I copied it to that /opt/logstash directory. It just seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-cloudtrail.html), you should be able to install it with the following:

```
 bin/plugin install logstash-codec-cloudtrail
```

EX: /opt/logstash/bin/plugin install logstash-codec-cloudtrail works for me with logstash 1.5.0.1.